# Python initialize strings as variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a calculation schema as string

```
calc = "((k+m+46)/2)"
```

and some strings containing variable like

```
m = 2
k = m*2
```

all only strings. Now I want to initialize them into Python.
my goal is it to calculate with the calculating schema the varible values.

calc should return 26

Edit:

I try to exec the vars but in some cases I have to exec the k = m*2 at first and I get error m is not defined!

Comment: `exec('m=2;k=m*2;print ((k+m+46)/2)')`

Comment: General secure way of doing this would be using a [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for evaluating symbolic equations. To convert string to computable expressions you may use [sympy parsing capabilities](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html).

Comment: `calc should return`??? Variables can't return...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

m = 2
k = m*2
calc = "((k+m+46)/2)"

result = eval(calc)

print result
```

Result

```
26
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use format strings. You can rewrite your equation as `calc = "({m} + {k} + 46) / 2"
answer = eval(calc.format(m = 2, k=4)). I recommend use of some specialised library as mentioned above in comments though.